# Magento Override Model Resource Category Tree file

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise

Trying to override app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category\tree.php with config.xml

```
<global>
  <models>
    <catalog_resource>
      <rewrite>
         <category>Namespce_Modulename_Model_Resource_Category_Tree</category>
      </rewrite>
    </catalog_resource>
 </models>
</global>
```

and my class is defined in folder   local\Namespce\Modulename\Model\Resource\Category\Tree.php

```
class Namespce_Modulename_Model_Resource_Category_Tree extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Category_Tree
{
  here is functions and code
}
```

it gives error  Call to undefined method

> Namespce_Modulename_Model_Resource_Category_Tree::checkId() in 
>   app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Category.php on line 671

While it is working fine if we put folder path in locally
app\code\local\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Category

Please help me anybody.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is working, use `<category_tree>` instead of only `<category>`:

```
<global>
  <models>
    <catalog>
      <rewrite>
         <category_tree>Namespce_Modulename_Model_Resource_Category_Tree</category_tree>
      </rewrite>
    </catalog>
  </models>
</global>
```

Comment: Hi,we have already tried but not working.

Comment: try with updated answer

Comment: great .......!!

Comment: you can accept and upvote

Answer (score 2):

use this to override the `category_tree` model. it is tested and working

```
<global>
      <models>
    <catalog_resource>
          <rewrite>
             <category_tree>Namespce_Modulename_Model_Resource_Category_Tree</category_tree>
          </rewrite>
        </catalog_resource>
        </models>
    </global>
```